# Can we get properties in foreach method listview backcolor c#

Tags: c#, listview, foreach

I have an listview, i change some item.backcolor is orange.

### So now i have an method and i want to be like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.BackColor.Orange)  
item.BackColor = listView1.BackColor;
```

The part (BackColor.Orange) is absolutely wrong.
Can foreach method can be written like that some how?

### I know that code can write like this but i dont want:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items))  
if (item.BackColor == Color.Orange)  
item.BackColor = listView1.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Linq using `Where`:

```
foreach (var item in listView1
                .Items
                .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                .Where(i => i.BackColor == Color))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
foreach(var item in listView1.Items.Where(x => x.BackColor == Color.Orange))
{
   //your code
}
```